# confused about keyboard settings does

Tags: input-methods

[image: image of macOS setting]

I'm confused what does this “show predictive completions” do, Google wasn't helpful

This ONLY APPLIES to CHINESE KEYBOARD, OK! READ the QUESTION before YOU REPLY.

https://support.apple.com/de-lu/guide/chinese-input-method/cim21aa5fa50/mac

Apple's website wasn't very clear what this does

Comment: My guess is, it is like Google trying to guess what you are about to type, for example, if you type "Imp" it would show "important" or "impossible" for you

Comment: @TangHo You are right. If you type "我”, the input method will show you "我们“, etc..